# How can I create more a more uniform data curve from my calculations?

Tags: python, json, matplotlib, physics

I am trying to take raw data from a rocket launch and calculate a variety of variables. The velocity I calculate is incredibly erratic, making it unreadable, as well as, unusable for further calculations. I am looking for input on whether my data is bad, my code is trash, or a way to *smooth* the graph without losing large portions of my data.

[The output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spvh6.png)

```
# Essa Hattar
# essa.hattar@wmich.edu
# the purpose of this code is to extract rocket data from a json file and graph its variables

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
import json

# set folders to pull from file
time = []
total_speed = []  # NOTE: turns out "velocity" is total SPEED not vertical velocity
altitude = []


def file_name():
    while True:
        json_name = input('Enter the json file name: ')

        try:
            data = open((json_name + '.json'), 'r')
            data.close()
            return json_name
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f'The file name {json_name}.json does not exist')


def extract_data(json_name):
    data = open((json_name + '.json'), 'r')

    # for every line in file
    for line in data:
        line_dict = json.loads(line)
        # sets data from dict into folders
        time.append(line_dict.get('time'))
        total_speed.append(line_dict.get('velocity'))
        altitude.append(line_dict.get('altitude'))

    # close file b/c not needed anymore
    data.close()
    return time, total_speed, altitude


def calc_vert_velocity(time, altitude):
    # velocity == change in distance/ time
    velocity = [0]
    time_v = [0]  # time and velocity folder need to be same length for graph, so I need a new time folder
    # these are all the "start" variables that I will refer too
    time_last = 0
    altitude_last = 0

    for i in range(len(time)):
        if altitude_last != altitude[i]:
            # calc
            velocity_temp = (altitude[i] - altitude_last) / (time[i] - time_last)
            # velocity_temp *= 1000  # convert to meters
            velocity_temp = round(velocity_temp, 2)
            # append folder
            velocity.append(velocity_temp)
            time_v.append(time[i])
            # set condition variables
            time_last = time[i]
            altitude_last = altitude[i]

    return velocity, time_v


def calc_acceleration(time_v, velocity):
    pass


def show_graph(json_name, time, altitude, velocity, time_v):

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))


    # altitude/time
    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.plot(time, altitude, 'g')
    plt.title('Altitude/Time')
    plt.xlabel('Seconds')
    plt.ylabel('Km')


    # velocity/time
    plt.subplot(122)

    # here down is with spline
    x = np.array(time_v)
    y = np.array(velocity)
 
    X_Y_Spline = make_interp_spline(x, y)

    # Returns evenly spaced numbers
    # over a specified interval.
    X_ = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 200)
    Y_ = X_Y_Spline(X_)
    plt.plot(X_, Y_, 'b')
    # here up is with spline

    """
    plt.plot(time_v, velocity, 'b', linewidth=.5)  # without spline
    """

    plt.title('Velocity/Time')
    plt.xlabel('Seconds')
    plt.ylabel('Km/s')


    plt.suptitle(f'{json_name} Telemetry')
    plt.show()


def main():
    # get file name from user
    json_name = file_name()

    time, total_speed, altitude = extract_data(json_name)
    velocity, time_v = calc_vert_velocity(time, altitude)
    show_graph(json_name, time, altitude, velocity, time_v)


main()
```

For **calc_vert_velocity()**;

I have made the data *more* readable by only calculating the velocity when there is a measured change in altitude. This removed many unnecessary zeros from the data. I have tried re-writing the equation in different forms.

I am considering calculating the average of a group of 3 to 5 points. However, I am reluctant t do so as it feels like data tampering.

With **matplotlib**;

One solution I iterated was using **make_interp_spline()** to manually *smooth* the data curve.

Here is the link to the data I am using
https://data.world/argoolsbee/spacex-launch-telemetry/workspace/file?filename=CRS-11+raw.json. You can use any of those files, they all work with this code.

I'd like to see if there is an error in my logic before I comb through the data by hand.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. actually numpy has some built in functions to make 1d derivatives, which could be really straightforward to your problem, see: [Numpy.gradient](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html).

Apart from this, from what you have calculated, you can always "smooth" your data with a Gaussian filter for example, scipy has a built in function to do this as well, see: [scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d.html).

Last, but not least, if you think that the data changes on your raw data may be abrupt because they lack of resolution, but you trust the data, you can always generate data between your points with interpolated data, scipy has a built in function for this as well, see: [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html)
.

So basically there are a lot of manners to answer this and a combination of those functions may worth a try as well.

Hope this is usefull for you.